# Can't access data from ViewModel?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, model-view-controller, viewmodel

I have view model which contains two tables however if I am updating my entity framework e.g.

View Model:

```
public class MyViewModel
{
public IEnumerable<Telephone_Search.Models.tbl_pics> images;
public IEnumerable<Telephone_Search.Models.tbl_users> users;
}
```

Controller :

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(tbl_pics pic, HttpPostedFileBase file)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            if (file != null)
            {
                file.SaveAs(HttpContext.Server.MapPath("~/Images/")
                                                      + file.FileName);
                byte[] data = new byte[] { };
                using (var binaryReader = new BinaryReader(file.InputStream))
                {
                    data = binaryReader.ReadBytes(file.ContentLength);
                }
               pic.picture = file.FileName;
               pic.user_no = 20173;
               db.tbl_pics.Add(pic);
               db.SaveChanges();
            }
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

        return View(pic);
    }
```

and then use a view model within my razor view e.g. @model ViewModel and try to loop through the users by :

```
@foreach (var img in Model.images) {
<img src="~/images/@pic.picture" width="100" height="100" />
}
```

The values are returned as null?

Thank you

Comment: Please post your controller code to see how the view is being served.

Comment: some more code of your controller would be usefull

Comment: Looks like your controller code is returning `img` and your view is expecting a viewmodel with a `Users` property. You sure you're passing around the right values?

Comment: @ToddSprang I'm not sure how to save changes to entity framework and pass the values towards a viewmodel?

Comment: @Djeroen , codes been updated!

Comment: I have attempted return this.View(new MyViewModel
            {
                users = pic
            }); , but no luck :(!

Comment: have you tried putting a breakpoint in the controller?

Comment: I can't access my breakpoints as the application crashes at Object reference not set to an instance of an object. @Djeroen

Comment: where does the null reference exception occur?

Comment: @AqibMehrban at what line of code does it give the object reference error?

Comment: It crashes on the View where it states @foreach (var img in Model.Users) .

Comment: @AqibMehrban that means that you are not refering to the correct object, see todd spang's answer

Comment: @Djeroen how do I get my view to return values that are needed for the model in the view?

Answer (score 2):

You viewmodel consists of two collections, `images` and `users`.

```
public class MyViewModel
{
    public IEnumerable<Telephone_Search.Models.tbl_pics> images;
    public IEnumerable<Telephone_Search.Models.tbl_users> users;
}
```

However, in your controller method you are only returning the collection `images`. `users` remains null.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(tbl_pics pic, HttpPostedFileBase file)
{
    ....
    return View(pic); // you are only returning the images here, not the users, or the viewmodel.
}
```

You need to populate the `users` collection in your controller method.

Secondly, this

```
@foreach (var img in Model.Users) {
    <img src="~/images/@pic.picture" width="100" height="100" />
}
```

does not make sense. Where is `@pic` defined here?

Comment: @pic is defined within images/'pic' picture , the pic being the table which is under an alias known as users!

Comment: @AqibMehrban then you need to specify this information in the question.

Comment: @AqibMehrban Actually, reading your comment again, that also does not make much sense.

Comment: Apologies , also I am already returning users from a different action controller which works successfully as it doss return a view from the model however I'm not sure how to return the pic view from this action. Thank you

Comment: Apologies , its var img in Model.images and not Model.Users